# Need help calculating the gain. running into an errror. pls need assistance

Tags: c++

my program is an automated stock market that reads data from a file and prints it out on the screen or write to a file. i am able to read the file and display it on the screen but i am running into an error trying to calculate the gain.
Below is my code:

```
istream& operator>>(istream& ins, stockType& stock)
 {//member variables are all declared as a double
   ins>>stock.todays_open_price
      >>stock.todays_close_price
      >>stock.todays_high_price
      >>stock.prev_low_price
      >>stock.prev_close_price;
      calculateGain(stock.todays_close_price, stock_prev_close_price);
      return ins;
  }

 void stockType::calculateGain(double close, double prev)
        {  // gain was declared in the header file as a private member
           //variable to store the gain calculated.
           gain = ((close-prev)/(prev));
         }
  ostream& operator<<(ostream& outs, const stockType& stock)
  {        
     outs<<stock.getOpenprice()
         <<stock.getCloseprice()
         <<stock.getPrevLowPrice()
         <<stock.getPrevClosePrice()
         <<stock.getGain()
         return outs
   }

    //double getGain() was declared in the header file also as
     double getGain() {return gain;}
```

below is the error im getting:
stockType.cpp: In function ‘std::ifstream& operator>>(std::ifstream&, stockType&)’:
stockType.cpp:38: error: ‘calculateGain’ was not declared in this scope

Comment: its a member of stockType. i declared it in the header file.

Answer (score 0):

The function `calculateGain` is a member of the class `stockType`; it's something an instance of `stockType` can do. The overloaded `operator>>` (which is not a member of `stockType`) invokes it without such an instance, which is illegal. Try this:

```
istream& operator>>(istream& ins, stockType& stock)
{
  ...
  stock.calculateGain(stock.todays_close_price, stock.prev_close_price);
  ...
}
```

Comment: hello beta, if i want to round the gain to 2 decimal points in the calculateGain() scope. how do i go about that

Comment: @Emy: 1) learn to cast a `double` to an `int`, and notice that it truncates, 2) learn to use this to *round*, instead of truncating, 3) learn to round to the nearest 0.01 instead of the nearest integer.

Comment: one more thing beta. when i read a double from the file 80.00, on the screen it displays 80. but i want it to display 80.00. how do you go about that? And thanks

Comment: oh earlier the gain would return for an example 8.36474. but i want the gain to display 8.36 or 8.40